# How do I respond to an internal drag-and-drop operation using a QListWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I've got a Qt4 application (using the PyQt bindings) which contains a `QListWidget`, initialized like so:

```
class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
```

I can add items, and this allows me to drag and drop to reorder the list.  But how do I get notification when the list gets reordered by the user?  I tried adding a `dropMimeData(self, index, data, action)` method to the class, but it never gets called.

Comment: The answer from @Chani (not the currently accepted answer) is the easiest solution to this.

Comment: possible I'm doing something from but the answer from @Chani didn't work in my example for PyQt5.  The accepted answer did work as did overriding QDropEvent as in my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had to deal with this and it's a pain in the ass but here's what to do:

You have to install an `eventFilter` on your `ListWidget` subclass and then watch for the `ChildRemoved` event. This event covers moves as well as removal, so it should work for re-arranging items with drag and drop inside a list.

I write my Qt in C++, but here's a pythonification version:

```
class MyList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, sender, event):
        if (event.type() == QEvent.ChildRemoved):
            self.on_order_changed()
        return False # don't actually interrupt anything

    def on_order_changed(self):
        # do magic things with our new-found knowledge
```

If you have some other class that contains this list, you may want to move the event filter method there. Hope this helps, I know I had to fight with this for a day before figuring this out.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have implemented the code in PySide and is working well.

Answer (score 16):

I have an easier way. :)

You can actually access the listwidget's internal model with `myList->model()` - and from there there are lots of signals available.

If you only care about drag&drop, connect to `layoutChanged`.
If you have move buttons (which usually are implemented with remove+add) connect to `rowsInserted` too.

If you want to know what moved, `rowsMoved` might be better than `layoutChanged`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to find out how to use [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) formatting. This will allow you to format the code code in your answer and make more readable for everyone else.

Comment: rowsMoved() can't emit signal... I tested here it never enter slot when i move item by drag/drop. but item get change order

Comment: Note that the `.rowsMoved` signal from this answer tells you which items were moved and where, while the `QEvent.ChildRemoved` eventFilter in the accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 5):

I found [Trey Stout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528215/175584) did work however I was obviously getting events when the list order had not actually changed. I turned to [Chani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368113/175584) which does work as required but with no code it took me a little work to implement in python.

I thought I would share the code snippet to help out future visitors:

```
class MyList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        list_model = self.model()
        list_model.layoutChanged.connect(self.on_layout_changed)

    def on_layout_changed(self):
        print "Layout Changed"
```

This is tested in PySide but see no reason it wouldn't work in PyQt.

Comment: I have tested this in PyQt5, and unless I'm doing something wrong, this approach doesn't work, see answer below

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I was able to get my code to work using Trey's answer and wanted to share my python solution.  This is for a `QListWidget` inside a `QDialog`, not one that is sub-classed.

```
class NotesDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, notes_list, notes_dir):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui=Ui_NotesDialog()
        # the notesList QListWidget is created here (from Qt Designer)
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 

        # install an event filter to catch internal QListWidget drop events
        self.ui.notesList.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, sender, event):
        # this is the function that processes internal drop in notesList
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ChildRemoved:
            self.update_views() # do something
        return False # don't actually interrupt anything
```

Comment: It is much more convenient to handle the event in the parent instead of subclassing `QListWidget`.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but some ideas:

You should probably check what is returned by supportedDropActions method. It might be that you need to overwrite that method, to include Qt::MoveAction or Qt::CopyAction.

You have QListView::indexesMoved signal, but I am not sure whether it will be emitted if you're using QListWidget. It worths checking.

Comment: There is a known bug in Qt 4.5.x that the QListView::indexesMoved signal never fires. You are forced to install an eventFilter and handle it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `QListWidget.model()` approach seemed the most elegant of the proposed solutions but did not work for me in PyQt5.  I don't know why, but perhaps something changed in the move to Qt5.  The `eventFilter` approach did work, but there is another alternative that is worth considering: over-riding the QDropEvent and checking if event.source is self.  See the code below which is an MVCE with all of the proposed solutions coded in for checking in PyQt5:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class MyList(QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    itemMoved = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyList, self).__init__()
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        list_model = self.model()
        # list_model.layoutChanged.connect(self.onLayoutChanged)  # doesn't work
        # self.installEventFilter(self)  # works
        self.itemMoved.connect(self.onLayoutChanged)  # works

    def onLayoutChanged(self):
        print("Layout Changed")

    def eventFilter(self, sender, event):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        sender : object
        event : QtCore.QEvent
        """
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ChildRemoved:
            self.onLayoutChanged()
        return False

    def dropEvent(self, QDropEvent):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        QDropEvent : QtGui.QDropEvent
        """

        mime = QDropEvent.mimeData()  # type: QtCore.QMimeData
        source = QDropEvent.source()

        if source is self:
            super(MyList, self).dropEvent(QDropEvent)
            self.itemMoved.emit()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
form = MyList()
for text in ("one", "two", "three"):
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(text)
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
    form.addItem(item)

form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```